# GridView date filter search box to be empty

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have the below widget to display date based on my database. However, in my search box, it would pre-select the today's date. I would like to leave it as empty. Any suggestion how can I make it empty?

```
[
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE_RANGE,
    'label' => 'Date',
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'format' => ['date', 'php:Y-m-d'],
    'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'presetDropdown' => true,
        'convertFormat' => true,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'locale' => [
                'format' => 'Y-m-d',
            ],
            'opens' => 'left',
            'autoclose' => true,
            'todayHighlight' => false,
            'allowClear' => true,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the placeholder that is shown by default with **your** specific settings you need to remove the `'presetDropdown' => true,` option from the `filterWidgetOptions` and it will remove the placeholder.